# Shell Scripting - Start Multiple Scripts under different user

Tags: shell, privileges

I have to restart 100's of scripts for at least 20+ users once the server restarts for any reason. I wanted to come up with a single script to trigger of all scripts/programs under all users with just one script (without root privilege).

Is it possible to do so? Linux If not, what is the best approach to proceed?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can make a boot script in `/etc/init.d/rc3.d` that will use `su - someuser -c somescript` for the different users.
When you want the different users to control which scripts they want, you can give them control over the `somescript` (perhaps `$HOME/bin/startme.sh`).
When you are anxious that the scripts are always running, you can consider another approach: do not start them at a server restart, but put them in monitoring script in the users crontab. Each minute (or 5 minutes or hour) this monitor script can check the running scripts and restart them when needed.

Comment: Let's just say all the users do not have crontab set up. I was thinking of having one script with internal scripts with setuid on for all the parent users. this way I just have to trigger the script once and the internal ones run in their actual users without having to login (or) doing sudo/su

Comment: That's fine. I think it is most flexible when the root script will look for user scripts that must obey self-defined rules (location, perhaps how to set a pif_file and logging location, mode 700, whatever).

Comment: Walter, I am planning to have one script installed as root. But will running the script as another user does the same as running as root?

Comment: You will still have the rights of the non-root user. For scripts setting a special change-uid bit on the file permissions is considered unsafe. Look for a solution where you can write/execute everuthing as the normal user, and only use the root script when some high-over control is needed.